# Overwrite python logging configuration at runtime

Tags: python, logging

I have a basic configuration set in my project

From, for example `__init__.py`:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

And I would like to change the global level at runtime after reading user parameters. Is that possible without moving the previous lines after that?

A full example will be something like the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def run():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--debug", dest="debug",
                      action="store_true",
                      help="flag to indicate if debug should be enabled",
                      default=False)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.debug:
        # change the logging configuration
        pass
        #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    # call the application code
```

Comment: See my answer below for your question, just pointing out that `optparse` module has been deprecated, please switch to using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Logger.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...

if options.debug:
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

EDIT:

If you want to set the level of all loggers currently available you can do something like this:

```
loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
for logger in loggers:
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Or you can mimic the behavior of `logging.basicConfig`:

```
logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: This solution configures the level at a given logger (in the same file), it does not applies to all the available loggers like `logger.basicConfig` does.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!